# regular expressions, notation w|w and w|?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I'm trying to give regular expressions for the following languages {a, b}

[image]

What does w| and w|w mean?

For the first question, I have (b(a+b))*, but I'm lost on the second.

Comment: Read the ‘|’ symbol as “such that.”

Comment: @amd does the w stand for a letter?

Comment: $w$ stands for a string, i.e., the second languages is "all strings $w$ such that $w$ contains at least two $a$s and at most one $b$.”

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the second question: What are the shortest strings that satisfy the given condition?

Comment: (baa)a*, (aba)a*, (aab)a*,but I don't know how to relate them

Comment: First, those aren’t the shortest strings—leave off the $a^*$ for now. Second, you missed one—“..._at most_ one $b$.” Third, you can also have $a^*$ on the left.

Comment: is it a* aa (a+b) a*

Comment: No. This doesn’t include your string $baaa^*$, for one. Are you just guessing at this point?

Comment: a* (a+b) aa a* has to be it

Comment: That doesn’t cover $aab$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29862/discussion-between-amd-and-user270494).